# Connection refused в laravel

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

Есть система написанная на laravel5.2 запущенная на сервере с ubuntu(16.04 64bit) и lamp(php7, mysql5.7, apache2).

В системе есть задача которая запускается по расписанию и выполняется примерно пол часа, проблема в том что задача не выполняется до конца, а в лог пишет исключение:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
```

То есть изначально соединение с бд работает, потом примерно через 12 минут, при очередном запросе laravel пытается обновить соединение, после чего падает с этим исключением.

Гугленье проблемы дало совет поменять host в .env c localhost на 127.0.0.1, это не помогло.

При этом на локальной машине на mamp данная проблема не наблюдается и задача выполняется полностью.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так же везде еще советуют Порт проверить, ты проверял порт совпадает ?

Comment: Да. Если бы порт был указан неверно то ошибка бы при первом запросе падала. Тут же выполняется определнное количество запросов, а минут через 12 падает

Comment: А ты мог запросами базу положить ? И ты уверен что выполняется хоть что-то ? Может он там конектится у тебя просто много раз но так и не подключается, а потом исключение кидает. Настройки php для консольного приложения совпадают с настройками для сервера ? Помню у меня была проблема когда для консоли не стояло PDO вообще, я тоже долго голову ломал, пока не увидел что у меня 3 php.ini

Comment: Уверен. Вижу свежии записи в бд. По поводу настроект консольного и серверного не знаю где это смотреть. Для консоли отдельный php.init должен быть? То что pdo из консоли работает 100%

Comment: Ну не должен, но так может быть (несколько php.ini), ок а лог базы данных можете посмотреть, она там у вас никаких исключений не бросает ? может timeout какой стоит

Comment: посмотрел. нет ошибок. мне сейчас посоветовали поменять в настройках mysql interactive_timeout . сейчас попробую это

Answer (score 1):

Помогло увеличить тамаут в настройках mysql.

```
wait_timeout = 99999999999
interactive_timeout = 999999999
```